# Intersection 3 planes is a single point, then the triple scalar is non-zero?

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

I know that, if the triple scalar product between the normal vectors of three planes is non-zero, then they intercept in a single-point.

May I affirm that if the intersection is a single point, hence the triple scalar product of their normal vectors is non-zero?

Comment: Yes of course, it is an "if and only if condition".

Comment: If the triple product is zero it means that two of the planes are parallel and thus intersect in either _every_ point among them, or in no point at all.

Answer (score 0):

The condition reduces to

- $Ax = b$ has exactly one solution $\iff$ matrix $A$ is full rank

which is true by [Rouché–Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem).